# How can I make proper arrangement automatically?

Tags: c#, winforms

[image: Before]

My codes;

```
        label1.Text = "myLine1\nmyLine2\nmyLine3";
        label2.Text = "myLine4";
```

As you can see it, I lost line 3.

I'd like to make like this.

(I made it with several times of trial and error. I've moved "Label2" lower position. I'd like to find out some automatic arrangement between Label1 and Label2).

[image]

Comment: I haven't touched winforms in ages, but IIRC there are constraints in the visual designer. Make your label2 positioned relative to label1's bottom edge.

Comment: Yeah. That's what I wanted. "Bottom edge" anchor.

Comment: Anchors are relative to the parent control (in this case, the parent of both labels would be the form), not to other controls within the same parent. Also, they are "anchoring" the edges to the parent (meaning: if you move the edges of the parent, they will "pull" or "push" from the anchored edges of the control), not making their position relative to another.

Comment: @Jcl: in this case, winforms is less advanced than I seem to remember :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev there are other ways to do that (layout controls, and whatnot), but yes, if you are used to other ways (like WPF, or CSS positioning), winforms may look way more primitive

Comment: Thanks. All your precious comments..

Comment: `TableLayoutPanel` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be adding a `Panel` to your form (you can make it transparent and without border if you don't want to visually see it), and put your two labels inside that panel (make them children of that panel), with their `Dock` property set to `Top`.

There are plenty of other ways to do what you are aiming, but the most simple if you are beggining is the "panel + docking" mode.

Comment: Panel.. OK I will check it out as you mentioned. Thanks.

Comment: Is the Panel the easiest way to test it ?

Comment: What you want is actually the docking of the labels. The panel is just a way of having both controls have a parent which you can move and resize around (once a control is docked, you can't move it anymore, since its position and *[either horizontal, vertical, or both]* size is determined by the parent).

Comment: Got it. Thanks again.

Comment: I've just made it. It's nice. Thanks.

Comment: @Jason Glad to help. Please note this is very basic... there are more advanced ways to do this (there's `TableLayoutPanel`, `FlowLayoutPanel`, and very good third party controls to create layouts, or you can make your own, which make their own position/size calculations). They are definitely harder to use than this simple answer, but you may want to investigate them once you start making more complicated layouts, otherwise you may end up with hundreds of "just layout" panels which serve no other purpose, but are expensive to render in winforms.